# Knockout Js function not appearing on page

Tags: javascript, php, knockout.js

I have a js file named admin.js which has knockout js functionality.

```
function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.alldata = ko.observableArray();
  self.viewAllInvoice = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASEURL + 'index.php/main/learn_Ko/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      })
      .done(function(invoices) {
        alert("hello");
        self.alldata.removeAll();
        $.each(invoices, function(index, invoice) {

          self.alldata.push(invoice);
        });
      })
      .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
      })
      .always(function(data) {});
  };
  self.viewAllInvoice();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById('loanersclub_wrapper'));
});
```

I am trying to call the function in this page like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/admin.js" ></script>
<div style="margin-top:30px;" class="container" id="loanersclub_wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <h1>HELLo</h1>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">1</th>
        <th class="text-center">2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: alldata">
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Loantime "></span></td>
        <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.Amount"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The thing is that, I am getting this data from a controller since I am using php, and I checked the controller does get the information as arrays, but the js file is not getting any thing, I even tried using alert, but seems like the function self.viewAllInvoice is not getting called at all.

Comment: What's the resulting markup if you view source on the page? Does the script file load on the page? Is the URL you specified being posted to if you look at the network tab?

Comment: @TravisSchettler I just noticed, it says when I inspect the page, baseURL not defined in this part
url: BASEURL + 'index.php/main/learn_Ko/' ,

Comment: Sounds like you found the problem.

Comment: @TravisSchettler do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set the value of BASEURL to the base url of your website, or use a relative path in your ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/index.php/main/learn_Ko/',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  })
```

Comment: tried this, 
it says this
POST http://localhost:8888/ko/index.php/main/index.php/main/Admin/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Make sure you care including the leading '/'. If you are, there would appear to be some external routing going on. Try navigating to the URL directly via web browser: http://localhost:8888/index.php/main/learn_Ko/

Comment: I tried that too, but it looks to me its copying the url twice.